# Irreducible finite-dimensional representations of a commutative algebra

Tags: representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

I've just seen a corollary in P.Etingof's book *Introducion to Representation Theory* which states that every irreducible finite-dimensional representation of a commutative algebra is 1-dimensional:
[image]

The similar result I've come across before, characterizing irreducible finite-dimensional representations of abelian groups, requires a representation over **an algebraically closed field**, while Corollary 2.3.12. seems to apply to **any field** as shown in the screenshot.

Besides, the author uses Schur's lemma(Corollary 2.3.10.), which requires the base field to be algebraically closed, to prove Corollary 2.3.12. as in the following two pictures:

[image]

[image]

So I wonder if Corollary 2.3.12 is a stronger version of the proposition characterizing irreducible finite-dimensional representations of abelian groups over an algebraically closed field, or that the statement of this corollary is incomplete? Thanks in advance!

Comment: page 8, second sentence of section 2.2: Unless stated otherwise, we will always assume
that $k$ is algebraically closed

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks. I didn't notice this sentence. This is really a stupid question.

Comment: When I'm writing stuff with assumptions like this, I tend to repeat them at the start of each section. It's a very valid point for you to make. Over a non-algebraically closed field, representations can be $2$-dimensional, for example $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you for your patience. I think I do understand now.

Answer (score 1):

We prove by contradiction that $\rho(a)$ stabilizes every subspace of the finite dimensional vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field $k$.

Since every subspace of $V$ is given by a finite linear combination of basis elements, it is enough to check on the basis elements. Let $e_i, e_j$ belong to the basis elements of $V$.

Assume that $\rho(a)(e_i)=\lambda e_j,i\neq j$ for some $a\in A$, $\lambda\in k$.

$$\implies \rho(b)\rho(a)(e_i)=\rho(b)(\lambda e_j)=\lambda\rho(b)(e_j)$$
Multiplying by $\rho(a)$ on both sides
$$\mathrm{LHS}=\rho(b)(\rho(a))^2(e_i)=\rho(b)\rho(a)(2e_i)=2\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_i)$$
$$\mathrm{RHS}=\lambda\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_j)$$
$$\mathrm{LHS}=\mathrm{RHS}\implies$$
$$2\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_i)=\lambda\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_j)$$
$$\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_i)=\frac{\lambda}{2}\rho(b)\rho(a)(e_j)$$
$\implies e_i=\frac{\lambda}{2} e_j$,  a contradiction.